# Adding a numerical index to a categorical index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say for example that we have the data set that looks like

| client | client case | client payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 1 | 200 |
| foo | 1 | 250 |
| foo | 1 | 225 |
| foo | 2 | 200 |
| bar | 1 | 500 |
| bar | 1 | 500 |

Within Pandas, I can set **client** and **client case** to be indexes, but I would like to number these indexes within groups to have an additional column that becomes something like below.

| client | client case | client payment | payment number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 1 | 200 | 1 |
| foo | 1 | 250 | 2 |
| foo | 1 | 225 | 3 |
| foo | 2 | 200 | 1 |
| bar | 1 | 500 | 1 |
| bar | 1 | 500 | 2 |

Essentially just creating some kind of payment numbering system within each client case.

I could theoretically do this by creating some kind of list by iterating over the rows but I know that this isn't the optimal or suggested way of using Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would do

`df['payment number'] = 1 + df.groupby(['client', 'client case']).cumcount()`

output

```
  client  client case  client payment  payment number
0    foo            1             200               1
1    foo            1             250               2
2    foo            1             225               3
3    foo            2             200               1
4    bar            1             500               1
5    bar            1             500               2
```